# Content ID API - Getting 500 Error for Youtube Claim List Api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Getting 500 error response all time for Content ID API.

Example Url : https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/claims?id=CLAIMID1,CLAIMID2&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Api reference 
[Claims: get](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/claims/get)

Response 1 :

> `{
>       "error": {
>           "code": 500,
>           "message": null
>       }
>   }`

Answer (score 1):

[**You cannot access the Content ID API with an API key**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/#auth):

> All of this API's methods require authorization with at least one of the scopes listed in the table below.

"Require authorization" being the important part.  You need to use OAuth instead. [This document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/guides/auth) should serve as a starting point.

Depending on where your application lives (server-side, client-side, etc.) you will have to decide on one OAuth flow, which is described in detail in the document linked above.

Comment: As you see my example URL, there is access_token which comes after OAuth flow and i have a valid access_token which works for other youtube API'S.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen intermittent 500 errors when creating asset and claim objects. Sometimes these errors would be consecutive which indicates a service interruption on their end.